# Convert large text from Gibberish to Hebrew in C#

Tags: c#, character-encoding, data-conversion, hebrew

I want to convert Gibberish text (for example "îö"á äùàìåï" to hebrew).
So I used that code:

```
            string oldText = "îö"á äùàìåï";
            var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255");
            string newText;
            newText = enc.GetString(oldText.ToCharArray().Select(c => checked((byte)c)).ToArray());
```

The problem is that **GetString** receives only **byte**, and my knowledge of overriding it with a different function that will receive **Int** or **Int64** is very low.

This result with long text to convert brings an overflow error.

How can I convert the Gibberish text so it will allow long text to be converted to Hebrew (Windows-1255)?
My goal is to paste a Gibberish text into a textbox and the converted text will be in a different textbox...

**EDIT**
OK I changed my code:

```
string oldText = txtOriginal.Text;
        var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
        string convertedText = "";
        byte[] buffer;
        try
        {
            
            buffer = enc.GetBytes(oldText);
            convertedText = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255").GetString(buffer);
            txtConverted.Text += convertedText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Now I have a new problem - what if the input text contains Hebrew characters?
is there a way to check the encoding of a textbox?

Something like check if its Hebrew then skip the conversion, else, convert to Hebrew.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can get the bytes from Latin(Windows-1252) and then convert them to Hebrew("windows-1255")

Comment: The problem is the large text, all of the functions receives **Byte** as an argument and bytes have if I recall correctly are very limited.

So I need a way to or somehow override the **GetStrings** function or write something else that will allow to pass a large amount of characters without getting an overflow error

Comment: so just divide your text into smaller manageable sized   chunks

Comment: Well I tried this:
`string oldText;
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255");
string newText;
byte[] splittedText = new byte[250];
try
{
oldText = txtOriginal.Text;
for (int i = 0; i < oldText.Length; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < splittedText.Length; j++)
{
splittedText[j] = (byte)oldText[j];
}
newText = enc.GetString(splittedText);
txtConverted.Text = newText;
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error that u get?

Comment: It's not an error...
I run this and only get the first 250 chars from a pretty big string and not the whole string is converted...